# Reading and Checking contents of Word Documents

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i am new in vb.net and my trying to check the page `layout` of the `word document` where Margins should be as follows,

```
a. Left/Right: 0.4
b. Top/Bottom: 0.5
c. Header/Footer: 0
```

If the Layout is proper then its ok or if it is not proper then its should display a error message.

Same for `Font Name` and `Size` with `Bold`, if the Fonts are other than `Verdana` and `Arial` with `Size 12` or `16pt` then it should display the line in message box which doesn't contain the following requirements.

I am new at this hence no idea how to start off things any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Import the following line

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop


  Dim oDoc As New Word.Document()
  Dim wapp As New Word.Application()
  oDoc = wapp.Documents.Open(filepath)

      if wapp.InchesToPoints(oDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin) = 0.4 or 
wapp.InchesToPoints(oDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin) = 0.4 then
               MsgBox("Margin Warning")
          End if

   For Each xpr As Word.Paragraph In oDoc.Paragraphs


     if xpr.Range.Font.Name<>Verdana  or xpr.Range.Font.Name<>Arial then 
           MsgBox(" Font Name Warning")
     End if

    if xpr.Range.Font.size<>12or xpr.Range.Font.size<>16 then 
           MsgBox(" Font Name Warning")
    End if

 Next
```

Comment: this isnt working showing all errors on btn click i have checked page margins is also right

Comment: imports the micrisoft.word and add the reference it. what type error showing?

Comment: its displaying the msgbox errors whereas there are no such errors in file

Comment: @jigar check my updation